# ActionScript 3 - Live streaming: how do you listen for multiple FMS URLs?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

Sometimes I have live streaming services breakdown.

Everyone is completely helpless and the live stream suddenly ends.

If I can listen to multiple sources in one player, it can just play the new source.

I'm not planning on playing two at once, only having one or more backups I can start using if one breaks down.

I'm using this random FMS URL RTMP live stream link as an example:

```
rtmp://81.177.35.218/rtp/2
```

There are more FMS URLs [here](http://iptv-player.com/?id=database) that work.

Also, if the code looks bad, particularly under `public function onMetaData(data)`, 
feel free to fix and edit it.

This was a template, and that was one of the few parts I edited myself.

I would appreciate it if the reply contained the same code but edited. 
I don't know what I'm doing.

```
package
{
        import flash.accessibility.Accessibility;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.net.NetConnection;
        import flash.net.NetStream;
        import flash.media.Video;

        public class nsLive10_7castwesttigerss extends Sprite
        {
                private var nc:NetConnection;
                private var ns:NetStream;
                private var video:Video;

                public function nsLive10_7castwesttigerss()
                {
                        video = new Video();
                        addChild(video);       

                        nc = new NetConnection();
                        nc.objectEncoding = 0;
                        nc.client=this;
                        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
                        nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, onError);
                        nc.connect('rtmp://81.177.35.218/rtp');
                }

                private function startStreaming()
                {
                        ns = new NetStream(nc);
                        ns.client = this;
                        ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
                        ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, onError);
                        ns.play("2");

                        video.attachNetStream(ns);
                }

                private function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
                {
                        switch(event.info.code)
                        {
                                case 'NetConnection.Connect.Success':
                                trace('NetConnection.Connect.Success');
                                startStreaming();
                                break;

                                default:
                                trace(event.info.code);
                        }
                }
                private function onError(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
                {
                        trace(event);
                }
                public function onMetaData(data)
                {
                        for(var i in data){ trace(i + " = " + data[i])}
                        video.width = data.width;
                        video.height = data.height;
                        video.width = stage.stageWidth;
                        video.height = stage.stageHeight;
                        video.x = (stage.stageWidth - video.width)/2;
                        video.y = (stage.stageHeight - video.height)/2;
                }
                public function onBWDone ()
                {
                        trace("on Bandwidth Done ");
                }
        }
}
```

tl;dr

In AS3 live streaming, how do you make it able to play live streams from different sources and URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Make a playlist (simple array with rtmp url's) and listen statuses of NetStream and NetConnection. In case you get a bad status just switch to next url and so on.

Complete list of available statuses you can find here: [for NetStream and NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info)